# How to re-size (stretch start or end date) events on Angular UI Calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, angular-ui

I haven't been able to find out whether the following options exists in Angular UI Calendar (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) or not.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDurationEditable/

Here is the calendar init code

```
/* configuration */
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
        height: 'auto',
        editable: true,
        header:{
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month basicWeek basicDay'
        },
        eventDrop: $scope.onEventDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.onEventResize
    }
};
```

If anyone has done it, please suggest the property that I can use to implement.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean resize the slot? You don´t need to implement any custom property. The editable property of the event overwrites the editable property of the calendar, but in your code is ´true´, so when you resize an slot, $scope.onEventResize callback should be called.

Comment: I don't see that option. The cursor doesn't show <--> stretch arrows for me to be able to stretch the item. I have onEventDrop working perfectly.

Comment: In which view are you working? What is 'resizable' option? I don't found it on the doc.

Comment: I tried without 'resizable' as well, but, it is not working. Could you please help understand what you mean by 'In which view are you working'?

Comment: I think 'resizable' doesn't exists. fullCalendar has different available views you can check at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ Editable slots do not apply in Month view as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be resizable in the Month view, your events should'nt have the time part.

For example, an event with property `start: '2015-02-01'` will work while `start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'` wont. (but it will in the Week or Day view)

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that it only worked for me in the "agendaDay" / "agendaWeek" but not "basicDay" / "basicWeek" modes.